# What is the name for the design pattern of large numbers to convey statistics?

Tags: design-patterns, typography, numbers

Usually presented on website homepages, the purpose of this design pattern is to present a quick top-level overview of the company in numbers, aiming to convert visitors by establishing credibility and experience.

[image]

Is there a name for this design pattern?

Comment: A general term would be "infographic," but it normally includes graphics and copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Counter Landing Page

I haven't found the exact definition, I think because it covers a fairly wide group: time, statistics, quantities, etc. But generally speaking, the best answers on Google appear when searching *Counter Landing Page* as shown in [nicepage.com](https://nicepage.com/c/counter-landing-page) .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is some kind of social proof. That is a pattern used as a cognitive bias to convince people about the quality of a product or service based on how popular it is.

Here's an article that I think can explain it further: https://blog.crobox.com/article/social-proof-examples

Comment: I think the OP was asking about the design pattern and not the reasoning behind it.